# No carga el css en el hosting

Tags: css, bootstrap, codeigniter

Tengo un proyecto alojado en un servidor, me he descargado una plantilla de boostrap,al archivo welcome.php de CodeIgniter le indique la ruta del archivo .html

```
public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('/design/index.html');
    }
```

Pero al iniciar la aplicación me sale todo sin css y no se a que es debido.

Adjunto una imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿En el inspector de código del navegador es correcta la ruta? No se nada de _codeigniter_ Pero es lo primero que miraría además de refrescar la cache de navegador. Esto suele dar pistas de que está fallando.

Comment: Me acabo de fijar en las ruta y me dice que no se encuentra por ejemplo una imagen que tengo: `/BolsaEmpleo/images/profile-pic.jpg` cuando en el servidor lo tengo así: `/BolsaEmpleo/application/views/design/images/profile-pic.jpg` Soy nuevo con CodeIgniter

Comment: Si llevo todo el contenido de la carpeta design que es la plantilla de boostrap que me he descargado a la raiz de BolsaEmpleo funciona todo

Comment: Imagino que tendrá un template general y luego cada una de las vistas. Si cambias el directorio de los recursos, toca cambiar todas las rutas del template y de las vistas.

Comment: pon el código de `app/views/design/index.html` (al menos el header asi vemos como referenciar las plantillas)

Comment: Lo mismo que el de arriba pero... si no te funciona, puede que sea cosa de los permisos, ya que lo mas seguro es que tu hosting sea con linux y aveces los permisos en las carpetas no nos permiten leer sus archivos desde otro archivo Si fuera lo de los permisos y tienes interfaz grafica quitale los permisos o habilitalo para todos (que no es buena practica) o investiga sobre los permisos en linux y como aplicarlos en tu hosting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para indicarle a `Codeigniter` donde se encuentran tus archivos `css` o `imagenes` puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

Yo por ejemplo tengo al mismo nivel que la carpeta `application` una carpeta llamada `assets` y para hacer referencia desde una vista puedes hacer uso de `base_url()` que te deja una `url absoluta`.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?echo(base_url() . 'assets/dist/css/mod.css')?>">
```

Estoy mandando a llamar un archivo `css` que se encuentra dentro de `assets/dist/css/`, para las `imágenes` es similar.

```
<img src="<?echo(base_url() . 'assets/dist/img/user2-160x160.jpg')?>" alt="User Image">
```

Dentro de la misma carpeta `assets` tengo carpeta de `img`,`css`,`js` y lo que sea necesario.

Para cargar una `vista` no es necesario que llames al archivo como tal `html`, puedes hacerlo de la siguiente forma:

```
$this->load->view('design/index');
```